# Конкурирующие прогрессбары

Tags: java

Изучаю многопоточность и решил написать программулинку:
на формочке 2 прогрессбара, которые "конкурируют" друг с другом за более быстрое "выполнение".

```
public class MyThread extends Thread
{
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private double step;

    public MyThread(String name, int priority, ProgressBar progressBar, double step)
    {
        super(name);
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
        setPriority(priority);
        this.step = step;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        double val;

        do
        {
            if ((val = progressBar.getProgress()) < 1.0)
            {
                progressBar.setProgress(val + step);

                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Main.stage.setTitle("Finish");
                break;
            }
        }
        while (true);
    }
}
```

А вот и запускное нажатие:

```
public void startClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws InterruptedException
{
    Thread th1 = new MyThread("thread_1", Thread.MIN_PRIORITY, progress1, 0.001);
    Thread th2 = new MyThread("thread_2", Thread.MAX_PRIORITY, progress2, 0.001);

    th1.start();
    th2.start();
}
```

Вопрос предполагаю и банальнейший, но у меня не получилось различить их по приоритетам... Второй выполняется с той же скоростью, что и первый... В чем у меня ошибка?

Comment: А почему нет?)...Приоритет дает преимущество при выборе системы какой поток выполнять, но это же не значит, что она, система, не будет выполнять поток с меньшим приоритетом. Вы делаете в потоке слип, система видит, что поток уснул и передает процессорное время второму потоку, он выполняется. И обратно. Вот еслиб у Вас не хватала места для выполнения потока, то система бы начала выполнять более приоритетный поток, в ущерб потока с меньшим приоритетом.

Comment: сегодня прочел главу в "Философии Явы"... там запускаются потоки через ExecutorService... и там в run-е каждого потока идет цикл от 0 до 1 млн., в каждой итерации которого выполняется мат.операция с делением. и при кратности счетчика цикла 1000-че выполняется yield() на очередной поток. вот там приоритетность на лицо. щас сделал то же самое с прогрессбарами - результат тот же...
как продемонстрировать то на барах приоритетность?

Comment: @JEcho: почему бы не опубликовать как ответ?

Comment: @nightin_gale: не делайте `Sleep`, а увеличивайте счётчик на небольшую величину (например, 0.00001, точное значение подберите экспериментально), и продвигайте progressbar довольно редко: только когда значение счётчика продвинется на, скажем, 0.01. (Это надо для того, чтобы исключить из измерения медленные операции с графикой.)

Кстати, странно, что вы можете обновлять графику из фонового потока.